# MS ACCES Filter ComboBox ALL Option

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox, wildcard

In my MS-Acces 2013 project I want to show Orders in a Listbox. I want to filter the Orders with a Combobox by Company. The Combobox lists all the Companies plus an ALL option. The way I have solved this is:

CompanyCombobox:

```
SELECT tblCompany.Name as Filter, tblCompany.Name
FROM tblCompany 
UNION SELECT "*","<ALL>" 
FROM tblCompany
ORDER BY tblCompany.Name;
```

Orderlist:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblOrders
INNER JOIN tblCompany ON tblOrders.CompanyID = tblCompany.ID
Where tblCompany.Name Like CompanyCombobox;
```

*The CompanyCombobox like is pseudocode*

I do not like this sollution. I feel it's dirty. My guts tell me I need to filter over the Company Identity.

What is the convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as the row source of the combo box:

```sql
SELECT tblCompany.ID As Filter, tblCompany.Name
FROM tblCompany 
UNION SELECT "*","<ALL>" 
FROM tblCompany
ORDER BY tblCompany.Name
```

(It selects `tblCompany.ID` instead of `tblCompany.Name`)

Use this as the row source of the list box:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tblOrders
INNER JOIN tblCompany
    ON tblOrders.CompanyID = tblCompany.ID
WHERE tblCompany.ID Like CompanyCombobox.Value
    Or CompanyCombobox.Value = "*"
```

(`CompanyCombobox` is the combo box controls name)

The trick is the additional condition `Or CompanyCombobox.Value = "*"` which will show all orders in case you selected `<ALL>` in the combo box.

Btw: For sure you will have to refresh the list box each time you select something in the combo box.

Comment: Work like a charm. I feel kind of stupid not thinking of using a LIKE on the ID; I tried it with an = which worked for all the options accept the <ALL>.

Can this cause problems when the ID's are LIKE another.

I.E. Selecting company with ID 2 in the combobox. Doesn't this also show Companies with id: 12, 22, 23, etc.?

Comment: My sample doesn't use `LIKE`, and I wouldn't use it on the ID field at all. The `*` is used like a literal, you could use nearly any other you like.